# Mysql(mysqli) vs Wordpress - speed and efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I'm coding for a shopping cart and now i'm coding a page for user profile edit. now i can't decide how to take the user information from database. i can ask Wordpress to give me the data or i can use a function of my own to send a request directly to database.
both methods can give me the data i need. But which one is better?
i mean wordpress is a very complex script and for each request i make it will go thru lot's and lot's of code to process. but mysql is clean and direct contact with database.
in the other way i'm using wordpress and it's a bit weird to ignore all the abilities of wp and ask another one to give me the data!

which one is faster and more reliable?

Comment: I guess you answered it yourself - if you know what you are doing, why not use direct database access? If you are coding INSIDE a Wordpress  plugins or what ever - use wordpress

Comment: well in fact my main concern is for "number of connections" with mysql! cause im using shared host's for so many clients and i receive this err a lot. when i asked them why this happens they answered because Wordpress uses lot's of requests and connections to handle what u need.

Comment: Why not to ask about this very problem? Why asking about some indirect issue?

Comment: simple cause i wanted to know if there is any difference between them (and what it might be) so i could figure out what can cause the problem of errors. i wanted to know more :)

Answer (score 1):

Raw mysqli is not intended for the direct usage right in the application code. An abstraction layer is a must.
If Wordpress offers you such a layer - you have to use it. If not, or if you don't like it - you have to create a your own.

As of the speed - it never being an issue. So, don't bother at all. Just have your database sanely designed and queries well written - and everything will be as fast as it can be.

Comment: thanks but what about receiving err of "to many connection to database"? id there any difference between this two?

Comment: Of course not. It's about configuring properly mysql server and client.